# Lerna | Undefined imports post transpilation

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, lerna

I've encountered a weird situation w/ Lerna, Webpack & Babel where all my imports yield `undefined` value.

The flow is very standard, I merely import B from A. That's it.

Module B has a `prepublish` script that runs `webpack`, bundles & transpiles the code and outputs to `/lib`. It also specifies the output file `./lib/index.js` under the `main` property in its `package.json`. The webpack config is the most minimal there is and looks as follows:

```js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
  },
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }
      }
    }, ]
  }
};
```

The `prebublish` takes place during Lerna's `bootstrap` process.
So far I've seen no errors and all runs smoothly.

After bootstraping, when I try to import B from A, it yields `undefined` all over. (I'm running it via `babel-node`)

The minified/transpiled version HAS the data (as in - webpack was successfull) and it exists in the `node_modules`, which confuses me even more.

I've tried all the following imports:

```js
import { httpserver } from 'my-configs';
import * as x from 'my-configs';
console.log(httpserver);
console.log(x);
console.log(require('my-configs/lib/index'));
```

Just to receive the following:

```js
undefined
{ default: {} }
{}
```

Any idea of what I'm missing here?

Current dependecies:

```js
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
  "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
  "@babel/node": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
  "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
  "babel-jest": "^22.4.1",
  "babel-loader": "8.0.0-beta.0",
  "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.1",
  "webpack": "^4.1.0",
  "webpack-cli": "^2.0.10",
}
```

Comment: try to do: from './my-config'. this file not library.